# How to deploy Custom Dataformat in camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am running Camel inside Karaf.
I have created a custom dataformat by implementing DataFormat interface.
Now I have my custom class.

In order to make it visible to my camel route inside karaf where to copy this class file?

Please provide guidance.

Comment: you should ask this in camel forum also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just add it to my Camel application source code and deploy it with that bundle.  If you need to reuse it across several bundles, then you could package it as a separate bundle and export/import it appropriately I suppose...

Comment: Yes we need to create a osgi bundle.